# Use Office365/Azure to send emails

Tags: smtp

I want to be able to use our Office365 to send emails from a Craft. There’s many reasons including organisational security policies, control issues and potential psychosis.

Does anyone know how to set this up? Recent changes to Microsoft Exchange security means that basic authentication is no longer supported and I probably need an API key set up on Azure. (I am guessing). I need to be able to authenticate the sending user to adhere to site email poilicies. I just can’t see how it is done.

Any suggestions of leading questions would be welcomed. I have seen plugins for this on WP but cannot find anything comparable in Craft.

BC

Answer (score 2):

I have no out of the box solution, but maybe you could use https://github.com/bertoost/Craft-Mailjet and customize it, and get some code-ideas from https://wordpress.org/plugins/fluent-smtp/

Another approach could be to use https://plugins.craftcms.com/sendgrid and use as a Microsoft Connector https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendgrid/